# Receiving SRT stream with ffmpeg - very high latency

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to receive SRT stream from Larix Broadcaster and Larix Screencaster using ffmpeg v5.1.2 running on Ubuntu 22.04.
I could receive the stream and put it to a DeckLink card but the delay is very high (more than 6 seconds). The same apply why I use ffplay.
I tried the basic code

```
ffmpeg -mode listener -i srt://:20001 -c:v v210 -vf setfield=tff -r 25 -s 1920x1080 -ac 2 -ar 48000 -f decklink 'DeckLink Quad (8)'
```

as well as playing with all the parameters

```
ffmpeg -rcvbuf 3000000 -mss 1000 -oheadbw 5 -maxbw 3000000 -snddropdelay 100000 -latency 100000 -mode listener -i srt://:20001 -c:v v210 -vf setfield=tff -r 25 -s 1920x1080 -ac 2 -ar 48000 -f decklink 'DeckLink Quad (8)'
```

still the same result.
Also the same delay when I use ffplay

```
ffplay -mode listener -i srt://:20001
```

Is there a way to reduce this delay? When I tried with software such as OBS or vMix the delay should be around 1 second.
Thanks

Comment: For testing, try the following (video only) command: `ffplay -an -flags low_delay -mode listener -vf setpts=0 srt://:20001`

Comment: Thank you very much @Rotem
The latency is now reduced to around 1.5s
Can you explain the command?

Comment: I have played around abit and it turn out that the filter setpts=0 did the trick. However this does not work for ffmpeg. I cannot use setpts filter for input and using it for output result in no frame output at all

Comment: For FFmpeg, try: `ffmpeg -probesize 32 -flags low_delay`...

Comment: work like a charm, thank you very much @Rotem

Comment: Hi, Yury from Larix Broadcaster team here. Thanks for sharing the solution. Also please consider our article about the usage of latency and maxbw https://blog.wmspanel.com/2019/06/srt-latency-maxbw-efficient-usage.html
I saw you using these parameters with huge values which is not a good idea :) So please check the article, hopefully you'll find it useful. Thank you!

Comment: @Yury those are not huge values for maxbw and latency
According to ffmpeg doc, maxbw measured in bytes per sec, so 300000 equal 3mbps; and latency measured in microsecond, so my setting at 100000 only equal 100ms.
Thanks for the article though, i've been reading posts from softvelum regularly

Comment: @Stun3i I'm surprised about latency value - the library itself operates in milliseconds, I wonder why ffmpeg uses other measurement unit... Anyway, I'm glad our docs are helpful!